# Having trouble with my simple search engine

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with my search engine... I followed a tutorial online, but i doesn't print anything from my database - And yes, I already checked if im connected to the database. 
Can you help me out? :)

```
  <?php  
 session_start();  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '', "test"); 
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$connect->set_charset("utf8");


if(isset($_GET['name'])) {

    $name = $test->escape_string($_GET['name']);

    $query = $test->query("
    SELECT name, price
    FROM tbl_product
    WHERE name LIKE '%[$name]%'
    OR price LIKE '%{$name}%'
    ")
        ?>

<div class="result-count">
    Fandt <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> resultater.
</div>

<?php 

    if($query->num_rows) {
        while ($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
        ?>

        <div class="result">
            <a href="#"><?php echo $r->name; ?></a>
        </div>

<?php
        }
    }    
}
```

And my database looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trmzQ.png)

Comment: Why connecting both procedurally and OOP - ditch that first `mysqli_connect` - won't solve the problem on its own though...

Comment: show your form HTML

Comment: Have you checked for query errors?  Checked your PHP logs?  What is the resulting SQL query that you execute at runtime?  What happens if you execute that exact query manually?

Comment: `WHERE name LIKE '%[$name]%'` should be `{$name}` rather than `[$name]` as you've got it on the following line - better yet it should be a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with [bound parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating $connect both as OOP and with mysqli..
Also, the variable managing the connection is $connect, but then you are using an undefined variable $test.
Also the query has something strange.. is [ ] needed?
I think you are searching for something similar to:

```
<?php

session_start();  
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", '', "test"); 

$connect->set_charset("utf8");

if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
$name = $connect->escape_string($_GET['name']);

$query="
SELECT name, price
FROM tbl_product
WHERE name LIKE '%{$name}%'
OR price LIKE '%{$name}%'";

$results = $connect->query($query);
     ?>

<div class="result-count">
    Fandt <?php echo $results->num_rows; ?> resultater.
</div>

<?php 

if($results->num_rows) {
    while ($r = $results->fetch_object()) {
    ?>

    <div class="result">
        <a href="#"><?php echo $r->name; ?></a>
    </div>

<?php
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: are you passing through the parameter ?name=valid_name a name which is present in your table? I made a try and it worked for me..

Comment: I see that there is not input passing name as a parameter:
<input type="text" name="name">

your one is "keywords" but then you are searching for "name"

Comment: I mean, in my database table structure I called one of the elements "name" isn't that enough? 
It's still just showing me a blank page.

And I changed the "keywords" etc.

Comment: Emil, I think you are missing something in passing GET variable through the form. Try to call the script directly from URL:
/search.php?name=PRODUCT
where PRODUCT should be a valid value of a record "name" field  inside your table.

Comment: I actually have another question... Now that i'm able to output the data for example "net" how do i make a hyperlink to the page i'm looking for, for each individual link that pops up?

Answer (score 0):

My HTML

```
    <div class="search">
    <form action="../search.php" method="get">
        <label>
    <input type="text" name="keywords" autocomplete="off">
        </label>

    </form>
</div>
```